# How can I create a table with multiple panels in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Imagine I have two tables similar to

```
tableA = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(2, 3, 4))
tableB = data.frame(a = c(5, 6, 7), b = c(1, 8 , 9))
list(tableA, tableB) |> kable()
```

How can I get the two tables stacked one on top of the other with a title indicating the Panel A or B and the headers used once for both tables at the top of both?